# Div with tall text inside it floats my layout

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a div with a long text inside it that destroys my layout arrangement. Is there any way to split the words by any logic?

```
<div style="width:100px">thisdivmessesupmylayoutwithitslongchildtext</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way to do it:

```
<div style="width:100px;word-wrap:break-word">thisdivmessesupmylayoutwithitslongchildtext</div>
```

Using `word-wrap: break-word;` we can force the long word to move down a line when it reaches the parent `width`.

**Note:** `word-wrap` is a CSS3 property.

Comment: Correct but you could explain a little about it too.

Comment: then why not simply suggest a link to previous answer instead of writing a new one?

Comment: Thanks mates, it worked! Sorry for asking it again :)

Answer (score 1):

set "width:auto" and "word-wrap:break-word"

this code will set the content in div as per the screen size..as contents in div reaches to right end of screen it will go to next line.

```
<div style="width:auto;word-wrap:break-word">thisdivmessesupmylayoutwithitslongchildtext</div>
```